# Simple pop up in jQuery for multiple table rows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I would like to put a simple pop up in my table to display additional details regarding each row. I just want to ask for ideas on how to show the pop up in every row. Currently the pop up is only shown for the first one.

Here's my code:

```
@foreach (var name in Model){
<table>
        <tr>
                 <td>Name</td>
                <td>  <button id="@name.id">Show</button></td>
        </tr>
</table>
}
```

Script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#').click(function() { //what should I put in the #? considering that it would have different id's?
        $("#popupdiv").dialog({
            title: "jQuery Popup from Server Side",
            width: 430,
            height: 250,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                Close: function() {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
})
```

View Pop:

```
<div id="popupdiv" title="Basic modal dialog" style="display: none">
                <b> Welcome </b>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a common class

```
<td> <button id="@name.id" type="button" class='popup-launcher'>Show</button></td>
```

Then you can use [Class Selector (“.class”)](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

> Selects all elements with the given class.

*Script*

```
$('.popup-launcher').click(function() {
    //You can access elements id using this object
    var id = this.id;

   //Rest of your code
    $("#popupdiv").dialog({
        title: "jQuery Popup from Server Side",
        width: 430,
        height: 250,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Close: function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I don't get what you mean. I'm sorry, I'm new to this one.

Comment: @user4656677, Add a CSS class as I have added `class='popup-launcher'` then use `$('.popup-launcher')`

Comment: Thanks, now it's working, but I'm wondering why there are two close options.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('button').click(function () {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr').index();
    alert('In row ' + row)
    //$('table').find('tr:eq('+row+')').find('td:nth-child(1)');
    //pop code here 
})
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/4h9ypgcL/)

This way you can get all the data of the row where you click the button

Comment: Thanks for this but all I mean is a pop up containing the ID so that I can render an Html.Action using that Id.

Comment: @user4656677 you can do that id of button or id of row. you can do `$(this).attr('id');` for button or `$(this).closest('tr').attr('id');` for row